# What is the best way to paginate my json variable before unmarshalling

Tags: json, go, redis, pagination, nosql

I'm trying to use limit and offset to get a certain chunck my filtered data, how do I do it

```
var limit, offset int

marshalledOrders, err := cache.RedisClient.Get(ctx, constants.KOrders+" "+sessionData.UUID).Result()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("redis get err", err)
        return nil, errors.New(constants.InternalServerError)
    }
    filteredOrders := gjson.Get(marshalledOrders, `#(status=="done")#`)
    var orders []*models.Order

    unmarshallErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(filteredOrders.String()), &orders)

    if unmarshallErr != nil {
        log.Println("redis unmarshallErr", unmarshallErr)
        return nil, errors.New(constants.InternalServerError)
    }
```

Comment: Paginating *before* unmarshalling doesn't really make sense.  In order to extract a page of values, you must first parse the json and transform it into a structure that can perform such operations, i.e., a slice.  That's what Unmarshal does.

Comment: Are you sure, check this repo https://github.com/tidwall/gjson, I think you can filter and cap the number of results before unmarshalling, not sure tho

Comment: That package may API may provide a more direct way to do what you want. What is your main goal / concern with this problem?  If you are trying to avoid reading through an entire (and potentially large) json blob every time, then the only true solution is to stop storing all of your orders in a single json blob.  No matter how fast a json parser you use, if you request the last page, it's still going to need to read through the entire thing to figure out where that last page is.  Also keep in mind that whether or not you parse it all, you're still reading the entire blob every time from redis.

Comment: Yea I know I can keep the redis part where I get the entire value for a key, I want to load 6 more orders every time I press load more ( I'll get the hole blob from redis but I want to unmarshal only 6 everytime after doing the filtering )

Comment: I wish for example for the gjson package to provide a cap on how many results you can get, another way is to save them client side, which I'm also tried to learn how to do ( using nextjs )

Comment: Still can't find an answer, I guess I'll have to paginate the unmarshalled output